# Mostrar nombres de columnas de un crosstab en Powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

En Powerbuilder, necesito mostrar los nombres de las columnas de un crosstab datawindows

```
//Click en el boton
dw_fichas_datos.settransobject(sqlcd)
dw_fichas_datos.retrieve()
dw_fichas_datos.object.datawindow.crosstab.staticmode='Yes';
```

En el datawindows visual me muestra correctamente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al exportarlo a un archivo plano, no aparecen los nombres de las columnas, alguna idea?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

Tienes por ejemplo:

- `select cod_user from tabla_user;`

luego en la `datawindows`, has modificado los títulos de las columnas en lugar de `cod_user` para que sean "Codigo Usuario", y en el export te vuelve a poner `cod_user`!?

**Modifica la select de la dw dándole directamente el nuevo nombre a la columna**

```
Select cod_user as Codigo_Usuario from tabla_user
```